# Android - How to open a fragment from current fragment activity on clicking a URL in WebView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent

I have a fragment activity with a WebView in which I want to open or redirect to a different fragment when clicking on a specific url.

**Note:** If a different url other than the required one is selected it should open in the same current fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the on-create where you have given the code for the webview add this(better to add at the end of the oncreate method)

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

then make a function call as below outside the oncreate

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

   @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        if (url.equals("your url here")) {
            Fragment newFragment = YourNewFrag();
            // consider using Java coding conventions (upper first char class names!!!)
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container(usually a frame layout) view with this fragment,
            // and add the transaction to the back stack
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

            // Commit the transaction
            transaction.commit();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should override the url loading.
Use something such as the following:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (url.startsWith("your_url")) { //you can also use indexOf, equales etc. 
        // do what's needed
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

});